# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jbdc://localhost:3306/rede_hoteis

Tags: java, jdbc, mysql-connector

I cant do a connection and i dont know why, it shows:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
> jbdc://localhost:3306/rede_hoteis
> at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:708)
> at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:230)
> at conexao.Conexao.getConexao(Conexao.java:16)
> at DAO.itens_lavanderiaDAO.cadastraItem(itens_lavanderiaDAO.java:15)
> at App.main(App.java:14)

Here are the codes:

**App.java:**

```
import DAO.itens_lavanderiaDAO;
import entitys.itens_lavanderia;
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        itens_lavanderia item1 = new itens_lavanderia();
        item1.setDescricao("lavagemzinha");
        item1.setUnidade(2);
        item1.setValor(21.5);

        new itens_lavanderiaDAO().cadastraItem(item1);
        
    }
}
```

**Conexao.java:**

```
package conexao;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class Conexao{
    private static final String url = "jbdc://localhost:3306/rede_hoteis";
    private static final String user = "root";
    private static final String password = "1234";

    private static Connection conn;

    public static Connection getConexao(){
        try {
            if(conn == null){
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            }
            return conn;
            
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to delete the `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");`

**Itens_lavanderia.java:**

```
package DAO;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import conexao.Conexao;
import entitys.itens_lavanderia;

public class itens_lavanderiaDAO {
    public void cadastraItem(itens_lavanderia item){
        String sql = "INSERT INTO itens_lavanderia (descricao, valor_unitario, unidade) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            ps = Conexao.getConexao().prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, item.getDescricao());
            ps.setDouble(2, item.getValor());
            ps.setInt(3, item.getUnidade());

            ps.execute();
            ps.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MySQL JDBC database URL needs to be in this format: `jdbc:mysql://<dbhost>:<dbport>/<dbname>` (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html )

So I guess you need to change your `url` to this:

```
    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rede_hoteis";
```